# Load SVG into a specific div with Snap SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

What is the correct way to load an SVG file into a specific div using [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/)?

Following the documentation I have this JS:

```
var s = Snap();
Snap.load("fox.svg", function (f) {
    s.append(f.select("g#fox"));
});
```

This loads the SVG just above the `body` tag, however if I try to set it's location, nothing happens, there is no error. This is what I have attempted so far:

```
var s = Snap('#myDiv');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think `#myDiv` might need to be an SVG element, ex: `<svg id="myDiv"></svg>`

Comment: Tried that... unfortunately not. I just get an error: `Cannot call method 'append' of null`

Comment: The script needs to execute once the document has loaded. The append will be `null` as the ID selector will fail if the script is executing before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work, its not far removed from your example, so its hard to tell whats wrong with yours without a live example and the svg to look at.

If you want to upload a fiddle or something, it may help.

```
var s = Snap("#svgdiv");
var l = Snap.load("path.svg", onSVGLoaded ) ;

function onSVGLoaded( data ){ 
    s.append( data );
}
```

Edit: Just to extend on Duopixels answer, the element you are trying to add, should be an svg element (ie

```
<svg id="mysvgtoload">...</svg> // you can add an svg to a div
<g id="mygrouptoload">...</g> // you can't add this to a div, but could to an svg element
```

in the file) or add the element (g or path or whatever) to an existing svg tag/element in your html. I suspect you may be trying to add a  element direct to a div, which won't work, but its hard to tell without the file.

Also double check that Snap is loaded fine, and you can do a console.log( data ) in the function to check that it has loaded the  markup correct.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it was very useful. You were right, initially I was attempting to render the `SVG` within a `<div>` element.