# how to resize a large svg to fit inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

I have the following div inside `<body>`.

```
<div style="width:320px; height:480px;">
    <svg id="svg1"></svg>            
</div>
```

I want to fit a 640X480 svg inside this div. I have tried this:

```
var paper=Snap("#svg1");
Snap.load("somesvg.svg",function(f){ 
 paper.append(f);
 }); 
 paper.attr({ 
 width:320, height:480
 })
```

But the svg is cut off from the right size.

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Also tell us about Snap.load(), it looks like it is async?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nahid/9zRR8/3/

Comment: Here is an old post discussing the problems with loading an svg in a div with Snap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110422/load-svg-into-a-specific-div-with-snap-svg

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was wondering about adjusting the viewBox for this, so something like...

```
<div style="width:320px; height:480px;">
    <svg id="svg1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 640 480" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax"></svg>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9zRR8/5/

Comment: strange, but I get Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYmax"

Comment: I think the case is wrong actually, so wonder if something has changed slightly with how the browsers uses case sensitivity and how its dealt with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio has the valid values.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? If I change div width/height the size of the image that appears is unaffected.

Comment: It depends what you are changing, the title of the question is a little ambiguous (as the question specified an inner width/height). Are you trying to make it responsive, if so try setting the papers width/height to 100%, e.g http://jsfiddle.net/9zRR8/543/ if you mean something else it may be worth posting up a new question.

Comment: @johnktejik It is a long time since you asked the question but since no one answered. The value must be in camel-case, so the 'm' after 'Y' must be uppercase like 'xMaxYMax'.

Answer (score 6):

The SVG will not scale because it does not have a viewBox defined.  The viewBox tells the browser what the dimensions of the content are.  Without it, there is no way to determine how much it should be scaled up or down to fit.

This is kind of a failing of svg-edit.  It really should be adding one, ideally.

What you could try is loading the SVG into Inkscape or another SVG editor which should add a viewBox.  Alternatively, you could add one manually, as per Ian's answer.

Comment: Can you add some sample code.. I am getting svg element how to resize it is my biggest challenge