# when hover over svg map display a popup with details

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, hover

I have designed a map on AI (adobe Illustrator) with sections and areas and exported the final map as SVG file to display on html page. Also I have the details for these sections in a separate excel sheet, I want when mouseover any section it will make a popup with the details for that section.

I need your advice on how to accomplish that.

Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be converted to json or a javascript object like this:

```
var xlsData = {
    "RedRect": "This is the Red Rectangle!",
    "Star": "This is the Star Shape!"
}
```

The best way is to use the javascript event load on a svg object to attach the mouse events. Because jQuery prevents to bind load events to object elements, we have to use javascript `addEventListener` to setup the load event.

[How to listen to a load event of an object with a SVG image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671623/how-to-listen-to-a-load-event-of-an-object-with-a-svg-image)

Inside the SVG file, we have two objects with the ids `RedRect` and `Star`:

```
<rect id="RedRect" x="118" y="131" class="st0" width="153" height="116"/>
<polygon id="Star" class="st2" points="397,252.3 366.9,245.4 344.2,266.3 341.5,235.6 314.6,220.4 343,208.3 349.1,178.1 
369.4,201.4 400,197.8 384.2,224.3 "/>
```

[image]

Now, all we have to do is attach our events when the svg objects loads:

```html
<object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="test-links.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

```
$('object')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {

    $('#RedRect', this.contentDocument).on({
        'mouseenter': function() {
            $('#hover-status').text('#svg #RedRect Mouse Enter');
            $('#hover-data').text(xlsData['RedRect']);
        },
        'mouseleave': function() {
            $('#hover-status').text('#svg #RedRect Mouse Leave');
            $('#hover-data').html('&nbsp;');
        }
    });

    $('#Star', this.contentDocument).on({
        'mouseenter': function() {
            $('#hover-status').text('#svg #Star Mouse Enter');
            $('#hover-data').text(xlsData['Star']);
        },
        'mouseleave': function() {
            $('#hover-status').text('#svg #Star Mouse Leave');
            $('#hover-data').html('&nbsp;');
        }
    });

}, true);
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OceDW30dCnpFM0DewzDK?p=preview)