# Access an element by class name from SVG using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, dom, domdocument, htmlcollection

I am trying to access `<g>` tag from SVG by class name (`ads`) and which is rendered using JavaScript into `<object>` tag of HTML.

SVG is rendered here

```
<object id="container2" type="type=" image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Using Javascript

```
player2 = lottie.loadAnimation({
            container: document.getElementById('container2'),
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: false,
            autoplay: true,
            path: 'assets/mindmap2.json'
        });
```

**But the issue is When** this function called, it gets `<g>` but in the console, it shows the zero elements inside the HTMLCollection.

```
 window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('ads'));
    });
```

**Microsoft Edge Console Log**

[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73xuM.png)

Comment: please try `document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0]`

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta I tried `document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0]` and `document.getElementsByClassName('ads').item(0)` but issue persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript function gets called right after loading the window. At that time, the svg picture has not been loaded, and its inner elements do not exist. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671623/how-to-listen-to-a-load-event-of-an-object-with-a-svg-image), you might find the elements by changing the script to:

```
const el = document.getElementById('container2');
el.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('ads'));
});
```

The script should be called after loading `#container2`. You can just add the script after the html code or run the script after loading the page.

Comment: Thank you for your response and time. Yes, you are right. What I was thinking that `listen` to the `load` event but didn't realize this. I got a similar answer on [here](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/2589)

Comment: So the code I changed to this :point_down:

`player2.addEventListener("DOMLoaded", () => {console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('ads'));
})
`